# tinymce tiny browser showing 404 error on web page upload

Tags: tinymce, http-status-code-404

I'm stumped at the moment- When I open my website: www.steubencony.org- I get the following console error:
GET http://steubencony.org/includes/tinymce/plugins/tinybrowser/tb_tinymce.js.php 404 (Not Found)

Now, this past monday we migrated to a new server, new IP address, and the works- this shouldn't have affected this though as much as it has. I checked multiple times figuring it has something to do with absolute path, and I've also been attempting to upgrade/update TinyMCE, but I need to get this solved before i can do any of that.

Here is the FTP path of the php file:
ftps://steube@gall.arvixe.com/steubencony.org/wwwroot/includes/tinymce/plugins/tinybrowser/tb_tinymce.js.php

What am I not seeing between the 2- I mean obviously the ftp path has the ftps, and the wwwroot folder, but I'm really thinking I'm just too close to it to see the simple error. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: script type="text/javascriptsrc="includes/tinymce/plugins/tinybrowser/tb_tinymce.js.php" is the code in the asp file calling this php file.

Comment: I just finished moving the file and re-pointing tinymce.asp to that place, still the same 404 error upon page load. Time to start reading up on absolute paths I suppose.

Comment: And I think because this isn't loading, I do not get the browse button when calling the editor, I get this a blank box where it used to be, and when I click it, I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined tiny_mce.js:1
k.create.execCallback tiny_mce.js:1
tinyMCEPopup.openBrowser tiny_mce_popup.js:5
openBrowser form_utils.js:67
(anonymous function)